# Object Not Set error when Excel VBA to pull HTML data from web

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have been using code from this youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sZRcaaAVbg) to have VBA in Excel to pull web data into my sheet. What I don't understand is that it worked perfectly at first for a a few weeks, but, without touching any part of the code, about a month or two ago I ran into an error that reads:

"Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set"

Here is the part of my code that the trips the error, where 'address' is the web address I want to pull data from:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Opening Web Page"

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = false

Dim address As String
address = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 3)

IE.navigate address

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.document

Dim askingPrice As Variant

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Getting Info From Web Page"

askingPrice = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("ds-value")(0).innerText)
```

Can anyone lead me to correctly setting the variable 'Doc' so that I can use 'getElementsByClassName'? Or show me if there is something else I need to do?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure there is a class called `ds-value` in the document? Try getting that first before adding `(0).innerText` to it and see if it's `Nothing` or it has a value.

Comment: I am getting a "Type Mismatch" error for it now. I think it has something to do with Doc being set as HTMLDocument, but searching through my options, I'm not sure what to set it as.

Comment: So what do you get when you use just `Doc.getElementsByClassName("ds-value")`? An error?

Comment: Sorry I changed something else before which gave me the "Type Mismatch" error. Now everything is the same as it was but the last line is now 

`askingPrice = Doc.getElementsByClassName("ds-value")`

 With this line I am getting the original "Run-time error 91" message.

`

Comment: When you get the error, while it's pending, go to your immediate window. Type `? Doc` and press enter. That will tell you if your variable `Doc` has been set. Does that give you an error?

Comment: When I type `? Doc` into the immediate window I get `[object HTMLDocument]`

Comment: Next, check the next object... like this: `? Doc.getElementsByClassName("ds-value")` - if that has no value, then that class is not used on that page... is it maybe in a frame?

Comment: I get a "Type Mismatch" error for `? Doc.getElementsByClassName("ds-value")`

Comment: Now try: `? Doc.getElementsByClassName("ds-value")(0)` - does that give you something like `[object HTMLDivElement]`?

Comment: No, I get `Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set`

Comment: Then `ds-value` is not used as a class name on that page. What makes you think it exists?

Comment: So looking back at the html on the actual webpage I think I found the issue. It seems that some of the class names change based upon other values. I am using this coed to pull info off of Zillow and for example, when a house is "For Sale", the value for asking price is located in the class "ds-value" but when the house changes to "Pending", that same value is moved.

Comment: I have it working now. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction to find the issue.